# no connector type ERROR in Confluent 5.4.0 ElasticSearch Sink Connector

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I have brought in data from twitter source connector in my Kafka topic **"demo-twitter-status"**

I want to sink this in ElasticSearch.
The connector I made is like this:

```
curl -k -X POST  http://xxxxxxxxxx:8083/connectors -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{
  "name":"sink-elasticsearch-connector1",
  "config":{
    "tasks.max": "2",
    "topics":"demo-twitter-status",
    "key.converter":"org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
    "key.converter.schema.enable":"true",
    "value.converter":"org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
    "value.converter.schema.enable":"true",
    "connection.url":"http://xxxxxxxx:9200",
    "type.name":"kafka-connect",
    "key.ignore":"true"
    }
}'
```

this is giving error as:

```
{
  "error_code": 400,
  "message": "Connector config {type.name=kafka-connect, key.converter.schema.enable=true, tasks.max=2, topics=demo-twitter-status,
   value.converter.schema.enable=true, name=sink-elasticsearch-connector1, value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter,
   connection.url=http://===========:9200, key.ignore=true, key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter}
   contains no connector type"
}
```

I have used `"type.name":"kafkaconnect" and "type.name":"_doc"` also but still the same error appears.

Can anyone please help me correct my connector.
Thanks in advance!!!!

Versions are as follows:

Confluent 5.4.0

ElasticSearch 7.6

**PS: The confluent docs says that 7.x is supported for confluent 5.4.0**

Comment: can you remove `type.name` and try again

Comment: thanks for quick comment. Did that still same error

Comment: can you check the elastic error logs and provide it

Comment: There are no logs related to connector in elastic search.
Since the connector is not created "error 400" how will elastic search have errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cause is shown in your error:

```
Connector config …   contains no connector type
```

You need to specify **connector.class** so that Kafka Connect knows to use the Elasticsearch sink connector.

Try

```
curl -k -X POST  http://xxxxxxxxxx:8083/connectors -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{
  "name":"sink-elasticsearch-connector1",
  "config":{
    "connector.class":  "io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector",
    "tasks.max": "2",
    "topics":"demo-twitter-status",
    "key.converter":"org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
    "key.converter.schema.enable":"true",
    "value.converter":"org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
    "value.converter.schema.enable":"true",
    "connection.url":"http://xxxxxxxx:9200",
    "type.name":"kafka-connect",
    "key.ignore":"true"
    }
}'
```